# AVFoundation: Malformed .m4a file format using AVAudioEngine and AVAudioFile

Tags: swift, avfoundation, ios8, beta

I have an issue writing data using AVAudioEngine and AVAudioFile using the new AVFoundation framework in iOS 8 beta.

I would like to write data using a tap on an input node using the m4a format. However, the output file seems to be corrupted, but changing the file format to .aac with the exact same setup, the file is well-formed and can be played successfully:

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

func captureMicrophoneInput() {
    var error : NSError?

    var audioFileSettings = Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>()
    audioFileSettings[AVFormatIDKey]                 = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
    audioFileSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey]         = 1
    audioFileSettings[AVSampleRateKey]               = 44100.0
    audioFileSettings[AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey] = 16
    audioFileSettings[AVEncoderAudioQualityKey]      = AVAudioQuality.Medium.toRaw()

    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode

    // by using .acc the output file can be played successfully
    let url : CFURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("/path/to/outputdir/myFileWithProblematicExtension.m4a") as CFURL
    var audioFile = AVAudioFile(forWriting: url, settings: audioFileSettings, error: &error)

    if error != nil {
        println("AVAudioFile error")
        println(error)
        return
    }   

    // Write the output of the input node to disk
    inputNode.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize: 4096, 
                                     format: inputNode.outputFormatForBus(0), 
                                      block: { (audioPCMBuffer : AVAudioPCMBuffer!, audioTime : AVAudioTime!) in
        audioFile.writeFromBuffer(audioPCMBuffer, error: &error)

        if error != nil {
            println("AVAudioFile error")
            println(error)
            return
        }
    })    

    audioEngine.startAndReturnError(&error)
}
```

I would be happy if someone could give some input on this. Thanks!

Comment: Bug with id 17495706 has been submitted to Apple.

Comment: Did you change your settings to use kAudioFormatAppleLossless for AVFormatIDKey?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I'm having the same problem. Using .acc works fine, but .m4a does not

Answer (score 0):

My Swift code isn't able to record to MPEG4AAC format, either, as of XCode 6.0/Swift 1.0 GM. Apparently the constant kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC is still improperly defined. The file is created but not filled with any audio samples.

The only workaround I could find was to build up the settings dictionary in an Objective C helper function:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)getRecorderSettings
{
    return @{AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
             AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @(1),
             AVSampleRateKey:@(22050),
             AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityHigh)};
}
```

and pass that back into the Swift code for initializing the AVAudioRecorder:

```
_recorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: fileURL, settings: recsettings, error: &initRecorderError)
```

Comment: Your workaround isn't needed: You can also create NSNumber from swift code. e.g. something like  [AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(unsignedInt:2), AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(double:44100.0)] works fine for me.

Comment: You don't need to create an AVAudioRecorder to get the audio data, he's simply tapping the microphone.